# Dojo/request undefined despite require

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, orchardcms, arcgis-js-api

In a script associated with an Orchard view I try to post an AJAX to server with `dojo.request.post` function. However, I only get `esri/request`, `dojo/request` is undefined. I call the request outside the function where the `require` statements reside, but there's no problem with other required packages as long as I use them in correct format. `Dojo/request` works in our other project, so I suspect Orchard of messing things up (the other project's `dojo/request` use is in a plain page, not in a view), though I would expect problems caused by it to surface earlier.

Important parts of the code:

```
require([ ... "dojo/request", ... ], function (... Request, ...) {
  //custom init function contents
})

function sendResults(featureSet) {
  //custom code processing the parameter, making uri, JSON and like
  dojo.request.post(uri, {
    //sending data
  })
}
```

My razor require part in the same file contains:

```
Script.Require("esri/JavaScriptApi").AtHead();
Script.Require("dojo").AtHead();
```

Those are defined in `resourcemanifest.cs`:

```
 manifest.DefineScript("esri/JavaScriptApi").SetUrl("http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/");
 manifest.DefineScript("dojo").SetUrl("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js");
```

The error I get when I try to run the code:

```
TypeError: dojo.request is undefined
```

I've tested it in FireBug and confirmed that `dojo/request` doesn't exist (the same for variants, like `dojo/Request`), only `esri/request` is a function, but it has no `post` method.

I'm stuck here. Google search lead to "plains of sheer desperation" (page 5+) with no useful output and my co-workers don't know. Does anyone know why I can't see `dojo/request` and how to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `dojo/request` does not export a global (as modern AMD modules generally shouldn't need to), so `dojo.request` would never work in any context.

The appropriate way to use AMD modules is to use them *within* the body of a `require` callback (or, even better, organize your own code in AMD modules as well, and use them within a `define` factory function).

```
require([ ... "dojo/request", ... ], function (... request, ...) {
  request.post(...);
})
```

Alternately, if you're certain `dojo/request` has been loaded by the time you want to use it, you could use single-argument `require` to reference it:

```
require('dojo/request').post(...);
```

However, this is typically not ideal and seen as a hack.

Perhaps the [Introduction to AMD Modules](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/index.html) tutorial would help to better understand optimal AMD usage.